# remove key value pairs in json file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to remove all instances of the key-value pair "start" from a json file, however, the code I am using below giving me an TypeError   -   TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

The data type for "start" is an integer so not sure why I am getting this error, and how to fix it. Thanks

```
[
[{
    "text": "- This video is sponsored video",
    "start": 0.15,
    "duration": 1.79
}, {
    "text": "where i talk about",
    "start": 1.94,
    "duration": 1.34
}, {
    "text": "Building Strong Habits.",
    "start": 3.28,
    "duration": 1.53
}, {
    "text": "Be one of the first",
    "start": 4.81,
    "duration": 1.16
}, {
    "text": "person to",
    "start": 5.97,
    "duration": 1.0
}, {
    "text": "sign up",
    "start": 6.97,
    "duration": 1.403
}]
]





import json

with open('transcripts.json', 'r') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for element in data:
    element.pop('start')

with open('transcripts2.json', 'w') as data_file:
    data = json.dump(data, data_file)
```

Comment: You have a list of lists, either flatten it, or go over the second dimension.

Comment: oh man how did I not see that doh. I checked it was a valid json but missed that. thanks for spotting